# Exclude NUnit test classes from dotnet test within source code

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have an NUnit test project called Tests. Within this project I have a number of files with their own class that run separate tests, including UnitTests.cs, IntegrationTests.cs, etc.

When I run *dotnet test project* I want only the unit tests within UnitTests.cs to be run, not the IntegrationTests.cs.

I want to avoid using command line arguments to ensure this. Is there anything I can write in the source code of IntegrationTests.cs to exclude it from dotnest test, whilst still being able to run them manually from the IDE?

Comment: Note my question specifically asks how to do this from the source code not using command line arguments, whereas the other question's solution involved command line arguments

Comment: You can split them into two different projects

Comment: @MindSwipe you're right this is one good solution. Alternatively if there's any flags/attributes etc I can use in the source code to exclude some tests from "dotnet test project" that would be ideal though